# Antonym for "resurrect"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am looking for an antonym for the word *resurrect*.

Comment: Are you looking for [this?](http://thesaurus.com/browse/resurrect) If yes will be your answer then, actually it is the first search result from google when I was searched using the keyword "antoym for RESURRECT".

Comment: please provide the context.

Comment: We need more context. You can [resurrect the project](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22resurrect+the+project%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), or you can [**bury** the project](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22bury+the+project%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example.

Comment: Antonyms depend on context. "The" antonym of *man* is *woman*, *boy*, *god*, *robot*, *alien*, *animal* — even though a man *is* an animal. Likewise, "the" antonym for *resurrect* could be the action of killing, or the action of leaving dead, or the action of postponing the resurrection, or something else I haven't thought of right now. **Whenever you ask for an antonym or a synonym, always provide context, otherwise your question simply cannot be answered.** And if you actually do want to have a list of any and all possible antonyms or synonyms, check out a Thesaurus. That's their whole job.

Comment: I vote for _inhume_.

Answer (score 3):

**Death, Extinction, Expiration** are some antonyms.

Answer (score 2):

The antonym will depend on how you view resurrection.

If you see it as a process of making a dead person live, then the opposite is making a live person dead and the antonym would be *kill* or a synonym of *kill*.

If you view resurrect as ending the state of death, then the opposite would be not ending the state of death. This could be to do nothing instead of resurrecting, which means the antonym is *dead*, or arguably it could be any action and hence any verb except 'resurrect', as in NOT-resurrect. The same argument says that the opposite of red is NOT-red, which is any colour except red.

Comment: ? could be do nothing ?

Comment: Do nothing as in look at the corpse, and then do nothing - leave it dead - instead of resurrecting it.

Comment: I understand, now you've explained, but clearly the sentence is easily misconstrued.  Perhaps italicize *do nothing*, and add a comma after it as well.

Comment: I din't italicise because I am not suggesting 'do nothing' as an antonym, but I will try to clarify it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

***Unresurrected*** exists in [dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unresurrected?o=100074) and is encountered in poems and literature. However context is required to establish the meaning and the relevant appropriate antonym.

Comment: The definitions in your link are all for *resurrect*.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to make a suggestion as the question itself does not clarify context.

Maybe **bury** can work in some contexts (but probably not really an antonym).

bury/resurrect

Comment: In theological circles, burial is considered the opposite of resurrection